# Adding polygon attributes (Shape_Area) to point data using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4

I converted my polygon feature class P1 stored in GDB to centroids by Feature to point tool. I would like to keep the Shape_Area and Shape_Length, native to original polygons, in my resulting Centroids.

I tried to add Shape_Area and Shape_Length to Centroid data by Spatial Join: the attribute table is copied, but the Shape_Area and Shape_Length are missing. I also tried the Intersect the data, without success.

Is there a way how to add attributes (Shape_Area, Shape_Length) from my original polygons to Centroids? I would like to keep the original polygon values the weight the centroids later.

I am working with ArcGIS 10.4, ideally in ModelBuilder.

Comment: This should be possible using the Intersect tool to transfer polygon attributes to the points that fall within them.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the Intersect tool, without success. I have updated my question

Comment: Did you calculate new fields to area and length before Intersect?

Comment: no I did not. I've just taken the polygon and intersected it with points. However, my polygons are store in a DBF, so they contain already the area and length columns

Comment: What parameter values did you use with Intersect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to complete [@PolyGeo answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/258466/115) (as it has took me some time to figure out what and how to copy the polygon data... :-)

When running **Intersect** tool over Polygon feature class (fc) stored in geodatabase with the point fc, **the system does not maintain attributes like Shape_Area and Shape_Length** (automatically calculated and updated in polygon GBD).

To keep the Shape_Area data to Point fc:

1. Add new field and name it (`copyArea`, Tool: **Add field**) to the
   Polygon data
2. Calculate the new field to correspond to Shape_Area
   field (Tool: **Calculate Field**):

Expression:

```
  areaCopy = [Shape_Area]
```

3. Perform the **Intersect** between polygon (with new fields) and point data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tool that I would use to do this is [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) which not only:

> Computes a geometric intersection of the input features

but has documentation that says:

> Attribute values from the input feature classes will be copied to the output feature class.

It is not clear from the documentation whether system maintained attributes like Shape_Area and Shape_Length are copied over but, if they are not, then prior to performing the Intersect you could add corresponding fields and calculate them to be the same.

The Add Field, Calculate Field and Intersect tools can all be used within a model.